# Change logo when navbar is collapsed

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I am working on a dashboard interface based on Bootstrap v3. The navbar can be collapsed, I was wondering if there was a way for the logo image to change when the navbar is collapsed?

```
<div class="topbar">
            <div class="topbar-left">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <a href="" class="logo"><img src="<? echo $appUrl ?>/system/assets/img/logo.png" height="40px"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Button mobile view to collapse sidebar menu -->
            <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="">
                        <div class="pull-left">
                            <button class="button-menu-mobile open-left">
                                <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                            </button>
                            <span class="clearfix"></span>
                        </div>

                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right pull-right">
                            <li class="dropdown">
```

Any suggestions please.

Thanks.

Comment: You should provide some code so that it's easier to answer the question in the right context.

Comment: @himanish.k I have updated with code! :)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can hide your "main" logo with "hidden-xs" and your "secondary" logo is hidden for sm and lg sizes

```
<div class="col-sm-x hidden-md hidden-lg">
   <img src="mainLogo.gif" alt="main">
</div>
<div class="hidden-sm col-md-x col-lg-x">
   <img src="secondaryLogo.gif" alt="secondary">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take out your image and replace it with a div:

```
<a href="" class="logo">
  <div id="responsivelogo">
  </div>
</a>
```

CSS:

```
#responsivelogo {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("path/to/logo1.png");
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 40px;
}
```

Then add your media queries

```
@media (max-width: 768px){
/*Unless you changed the collapse point, this is the default*/
#responsivelogo {
    background-image: url("path/to/logo2.png");
 }
}
```

Since you are using PHP to push the source to the image, you would have to put your CSS internal and put the script on the background-image selector's url.

Alternatively, you could also use this technique http://littlegreenfootballs.com/article/43278_Tech_Note-_Using_Media_Queries_With_PHP

If you're going that route just set a variable on your img src and then set the variable with the if/else statement he shows you on that site.

Hope this helps!